# Как получить подходящую URL ссылку для отправления файлов пользователю через телеграм бота?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь написать своего телеграм бота,который будет отправлять картинки пользователю. В мануале Nuget пакета(Telegram.Bot) написано что файл можно загрузить используя HTTP URL for Telegram to get a file from the internet. Я попробовал загружать фото на ЯндексДиск - получилась ссылка такого типа https://yadi.sk/i/6EpzeBsZDE**** ,и она не подходит.Других вариантов куда загрузить я не смог найти. Подскажите, куда можно загрузить картинку что бы в последующем получить подходящую URL ссылку?

Comment: Знаете что в вашем вопросе странно? Что вместо того, чтобы грузить файл при помощи одного API - вы хотите грузить файл двумя API (начала на хостинг, потом с хостинга в телеграм). Ведь ваш бот будет откуда-то брать картинки, их не будут руками грузить на хостинг, верно? А значит, вам нужен хостинг, имеющий API для загрузки, а потом писать код, который будет вызывать сначала одно API, потом другое. Это как-то нерационально, будто "летим из Питера в Москву через Владивосток". Загрузить можно и файл: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33757887/5752652 Вам точно нужна именно такая постановка вопроса?

Comment: В идеале мне нужен способ отправить фото прямо с пк, никуда его не загружая. Telegram.bot обновился,и в нем теперь нет FileToSend, так что пример что Вы сбросили не актуален

Comment: Мгм. У меня в проекте 14.11.0, метод на месте, обновился до 14.12.0 (последняя на текущий момент), чисто для проформы: выпиливание метода изменило бы версию в старшей цифре, а не во второй. Всё на месте, единственное, что могу сказать - что он async - называется SendPhotoAsync. Да и вон, в одном из ответов по ссылке тоже есть именно такой метод - SendPhotoAsync